# Immutable or Mutable data model, which should be used for designing the software like google form, google doc etc.?

Tags: flutter, dart, immutability

We are developing a software which would be write extensive as well as memory extensive in Flutter. And it would also support undo and redo features.
Currently we have zero experience in immutable data structure.
During the research of flutter, I came up with the freezed package, code generator for immutable data model, which motivated me to understand the immutable data set. But using of immutable data model giving various challenges like -

1. Updating of deeply nested children of the data model
2. Deep copying of whole data even on a minor change in any of the nested data model(Like a letter change in the google doc), would make our application slow.
3. We were planning to keep multiple copy of the the same model for supporting the undo or redo, but this will take a lot of memory space of the end user.

Answer (score 7):

> Updating of deeply nested children of the data model

Since you are using [Freezed](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed), this should not be a problem.
[Freezed](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed) offers a built-in mechanism for updating deeply nested variables

https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed#deep-copy

For example, assume that you have:

```dart
@freezed
abstract class Company with _$Company {
  factory Company({String name, Director director}) = _Company;
}

@freezed
abstract class Director with _$Director {
  factory Director({String name, Assistant assistant}) = _Director;
}

@freezed
abstract class Assistant with _$Assistant {
  factory Assistant({String name, int age}) = _Assistant;
}
```

Then that instead of:

```dart
Company company;

Company newCompany = company.copyWith(
  director: company.director.copyWith(
    assistant: company.director.assistant.copyWith(
      name: 'John Smith',
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can write:

```dart
Company company;

Company newCompany = company.copyWith.director.assistant(name: 'John Smith');
```

> Deep copying of whole data even on a minor change in any of the nested data model(Like a letter change in the google doc), would make our application slow.

When using immutability, there are very few reasons to make a "deep copy".
Instead it is a shallow copy that is performed.

To continue on the `Company` example, assume that you have:

```dart
var company = Company(
  name: 'Google',
  director: Director(
    name: 'John',
  ),
)
```

Then when you want to change the company name, you'll only need to do:

```dart
company = company.copyWith(name: 'Facebook');
```

When doing so, the `Director` is not recreated. Only the `Company` is, which is a lot more efficient.

It's fine since `Director` is immutable. We can't change anything on `Director`, so there is no risk of conflict even if two objects are using the same `Director`.

> We were planning to keep multiple copy of the the same model for supporting the undo or redo, but this will take a lot of memory space of the end user.

Continuing from the previous point, what you will store is not deep copies, but shallow copies.

So in the end the memory impact is reduced by a lot.

And as you mentioned undo-redo, even if you didn't use immutable data, chances are you'd still use that memory.

Comment: Thank you for resolving my misunderstanding about the deep copy and hence its memory impact.

Comment: Regarding updating of deeply nested children, I am facing few problems like - 
1. I have only the reference of the deeply nested child and I wants to update the same. For that I have to find the child from the tree and then only I can update. Is there any other better solution ?

Comment: What if instead of Director director field we had KtList<Director> directors and 
and instead of Assistant assistant we had KtList<Assistant> assistants. -
When I tried your deepCopy method, it is not working.
And same as the the first comment, if I have reference of one of the assistants, then how would I update the same.

Comment: Lists are not supported for deep copy. But you can still use the manual syntax. You can't update a `Company` from a `Director`. You'll need the company.

Comment: I also understood the same that it'd not be possible. Do you also feel there should be a similar code generator library for mutable data model ? If not, then please let me know the reason?